# Why valgrind is killed during memory leak detection?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, valgrind

```
==1581== 
==1581== HEAP SUMMARY:
==1581==     in use at exit: 49,152 bytes in 3 blocks
==1581==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 1 frees, 50,176 bytes allocated
==1581== 
==1581== LEAK SUMMARY:
==1581==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1581==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1581==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1581==    still reachable: 49,152 bytes in 3 blocks
==1581==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1581== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==1581== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes
==1581== 
==1581== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==1581== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 4 from 4)
Killed
```

Comment: So how do you expect us to know why this is happening? Show us some code or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some allocated blocks are still theoretically live at the time the check is performed. Perhaps static or global data that will be taken care of later. Or C++ standard streams that outlive the application code (never destroyed).

Here's a hint:

> ==1581== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
>   ==1581== **To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes**